# Ingame menu is not working correctly

Tags: xna, c#

The ingame menu opens when the player presses Escape during the main game. If the player presses Y in the ingame menu, the game switches to the main menu. Up to here, everything works.
But:
On the other hand, if the player presses N in the ingame menu, the game should switch back to the main game(should resume the main game). But that doesn't work. The game just rests in the ingame menu if the player presses N.
I set a breakpoint in this line of the Ingamemenu class:

```
KeyboardState kbState = Keyboard.GetState();
```

CurrentSate/currentGameState and LastState/lastGameState have the same state: IngamemenuState.
But LastState/lastGameState should not have the same state than CurrentSate/currentGameState.
What is wrong? Why is the ingame menu not working correctly?

```
public class Game1 : Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game
{
    GraphicsDeviceManager graphics;
    SpriteBatch spriteBatch;
    IState lastState, currentState;

    public enum GameStates
    {
        IntroState = 0,
        MenuState = 1,
        MaingameState = 2,
        IngamemenuState = 3
    }

    public void ChangeGameState(GameStates newState)
    {
        lastGameState = currentGameState;
        lastState = currentState;
        switch (newState)
        {
            case GameStates.IntroState:
                currentState = new Intro(this);
                currentGameState = GameStates.IntroState;
                break;
            case GameStates.MenuState:
                currentState = new Menu(this);
                currentGameState = GameStates.MenuState;
                break;
            case GameStates.MaingameState:
                  currentState = new Maingame(this);
                  currentGameState = GameStates.MaingameState;
                break;
            case GameStates.IngamemenuState:
                currentState = new Ingamemenu(this);
                currentGameState = GameStates.IngamemenuState;
                break;
        }
        currentState.Load(Content);
    }

    public void ChangeCurrentToLastGameState()
    {
        currentGameState = lastGameState;
        currentState = lastState;
    }

    public GameStates CurrentState
    {
        get { return currentGameState; }
        set { currentGameState = value; }
    }

    public GameStates LastState
    {
        get { return lastGameState; }
        set { lastGameState = value; }
    }

    private GameStates currentGameState = GameStates.IntroState;
    private GameStates lastGameState;

    public Game1()
    {
        graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
        Content.RootDirectory = "Content";
    }

    protected override void Initialize()
    {
        ChangeGameState(GameStates.IntroState);
        base.Initialize();
    }

    protected override void LoadContent()
    {       
        spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);
        currentState.Load(Content);
    }

    protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        currentState.Update(gameTime);
        if ((lastGameState == GameStates.MaingameState) && (currentGameState == GameStates.IngamemenuState))
        {
            lastState.Update(gameTime);
        }
        base.Update(gameTime);
    }

    protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);
        spriteBatch.Begin();
        if ((lastGameState == GameStates.MaingameState) && (currentGameState == GameStates.IngamemenuState))
        {
          lastState.Render(spriteBatch);
        }
        currentState.Render(spriteBatch);
        spriteBatch.End();

        base.Draw(gameTime);
    }
}

public interface IState
    {
        void Load(ContentManager content);
        void Update(GameTime gametime);
        void Render(SpriteBatch batch);
    }


public class Intro : IState
{
    Texture2D Titelbildschirm;
    private Game1 game1;       

    public Intro(Game1 game)
    {
        game1 = game;
    }

    public void Load(ContentManager content)
    {
       Titelbildschirm = content.Load<Texture2D>("gruft");
    }

    public void Update(GameTime gametime)
    {
        KeyboardState kbState = Keyboard.GetState();
        if (kbState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Space))
            game1.ChangeGameState(Game1.GameStates.MenuState);
    }

    public void Render(SpriteBatch batch)
    {
        batch.Draw(Titelbildschirm, new Rectangle(0, 0, 1280, 720), Color.White);
    }
}


public class Menu:IState
{
Texture2D Choosescreen;
private Game1 game1;

    public Menu(Game1 game)
    {
        game1 = game;
    }

public void Load(ContentManager content)
{
    Choosescreen = content.Load<Texture2D>("menubild");
}

public void Update(GameTime gametime)
{
    KeyboardState kbState = Keyboard.GetState();
    if (kbState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Enter))
        game1.ChangeGameState(Game1.GameStates.MaingameState);
    if (kbState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Escape))
        game1.Exit();
}

public void Render(SpriteBatch batch)
{
    batch.Draw(Choosescreen, new Rectangle(0, 0, 1280, 720), Color.White);
}
}

public class Maingame : IState
{
    Texture2D Spielbildschirm, axe;
    Vector2 position = new Vector2(100,100);

    private Game1 game1;

    public Maingame(Game1 game)
    {
        game1 = game;
    }

    public void Load(ContentManager content)
    {
        Spielbildschirm = content.Load<Texture2D>("hauszombie");
        axe = content.Load<Texture2D>("axxx");
    }

    public void Update(GameTime gametime)
    {
          KeyboardState keyboardState = Keyboard.GetState();
          float delta = (float)gametime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds;
          position.X += 5 * delta;
          position.Y += 3 * delta;

          if (keyboardState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Escape))
            game1.ChangeGameState(Game1.GameStates.IngamemenuState);        
    }

    public void Render(SpriteBatch batch)
    {
        batch.Draw(Spielbildschirm, new Rectangle(0, 0, 1280, 720), Color.White);
        batch.Draw(axe, position, Color.White);
    }
}

public class Ingamemenu : IState
{
    Texture2D Quitscreen;
    private Game1 game1;

    public Ingamemenu(Game1 game)
    {
        game1 = game;
    }

    public void Load(ContentManager content)
    {
        Quitscreen = content.Load<Texture2D>("quit");
    }

    public void Update(GameTime gametime)
    {
        KeyboardState kbState = Keyboard.GetState();
        if (kbState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Y))
           game1.ChangeGameState(Game1.GameStates.MenuState);
        if (kbState.IsKeyDown(Keys.N))
          game1.ChangeCurrentToLastGameState();
    }

    public void Render(SpriteBatch batch)
    {
        batch.Draw(Quitscreen, new Rectangle(200, 200, 200, 200), Color.White);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I have a guess.

You need to hit ESC faster :)

You have this code in your update:

```
if ((lastGameState == GameStates.MaingameState) &&
   (currentGameState == GameStates.IngamemenuState))
{
    lastState.Update(gameTime);
}
```

So that means when you're in `IngamemenuState` your game continues to update the last state `MaingameState`.

And in your `MaingameState` update you have this code:

```
if (keyboardState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Escape))
    game1.ChangeGameState(Game1.GameStates.IngamemenuState);
```

So unless you're super fast on hitting that ESC key, you're going to trigger this line twice (just twice because after `lastGameState` is updated again, `MaingameState` no longer gets updated):

```
game1.ChangeGameState(Game1.GameStates.IngamemenuState);
```

So, you're likely changing multiple times into `IngamemenuState`, which makes your last state and previous states both `IngamemenuState`.

Try setting a printout in your `ChangeGameState` function showing the previous and next states. I'm guessing you'll see two printouts

```
MaingameState -> IngamemenuState
```

and

```
IngamemenuState -> IngamemenuState
```

---

Try changing this:

```
 if (keyboardState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Escape))
     game1.ChangeGameState(Game1.GameStates.IngamemenuState);
```

to this:

```
 if (keyboardState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Escape) && game1.currentState != IngamemenuState)
     game1.ChangeGameState(Game1.GameStates.IngamemenuState);
```

Or something like that. Basically, you don't want to change into the menu, if you're already in the menu.

Better yet, just do the check inside your `ChangeGameState` function:

```
 if(newState == currentGameState)
     return;
```

You should also be checking all your inputs so you don't duplicate commands like this.

Comment: I set a breakpoint in each of these two lines in game1 class:
currentGameState = lastGameState;
currentState = lastState;
    CurrentSate/currentGameState and LastState/lastGameState always have the same state: IngamemenuState.
What should I change in the game1 class? I'm not sure how to change the update method of game1.

Comment: Yes, they would be at that point. See my edit.

Comment: I just changed this line like you said and the ingame menu works now.
if ((keyboardState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Escape)) && (game1.CurrentState != Game1.GameStates.IngamemenuState))
                game1.ChangeGameState(Game1.GameStates.IngamemenuState);    

But I did not understand how to change the ChangeGameState function.
How should I change the ChangeGameState function to improve the code?

Comment: Johnny, Not much learning if I tell you how to change everything. I've given you all the information you need to fix it. This site isn't about people telling you how to write your code, we tell you what's wrong or how to fix it and you implement the changes. Good luck! Glad it's working.

Comment: I don't understand what this line means. if(newState == currentGameState)
     return;   What is return? Why do you use return?

Comment: `return` makes it exit from that function without processing any more of the code in it. Because if they are the same, you don't want to do any of the state switching code.

Comment: I changed my code and added additional information. Switching from GameoverState to MenuState is not working.

Comment: Johnny, ask a new question if you have a different problem. I'm going to revert your question to the original one.